# Minimum point is not equal to zero point of derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives, vectors, curves

Given the positional vector $ r(t)=[ln(t), t^2 - 4t]$,

find the potential maximum/minimum points using the velocity vector.

$v(t)=r´(t) = [1/t, 2t-4]$

Plotted into my graphing software of choice, we can see that the x-point where v(t) has its y-value equal to 0 (marked green), is not equal to the x-point where r(t) has its minimum point (marked red).

**Why is this?**

[image]

Comment: What do apex/base points of $r$ mean? If you mean minimum, then the problem is asking you to probably minimise $|\vec{r}|$.

Comment: @samjoe yes, I meant minimum - corrected my question. What do you mean by minimising?

Comment: What do you mean with minimizing a vector quantity?